# List python multiply with certain odd number contidition

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, multiplication

I want to multiply `list_1` with only odd number from `list_2`:

```py
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_2 = [2,3,6,8,9]
```

Expected Result :

```
3
9
6
18
9
27
12
36
15
45
```

How can I get that expected result?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple list comprehension, with a test on the parity of list2 items:

```
out = [a*b for a in list_1 for b in list_2 if b%2]
```

Or, more efficient:

```
list_2_odd = [b for b in list_2 if b%2]
out = [a*x for a in list_1 for x in list_2_odd]
```

output: `[3, 9, 6, 18, 9, 27, 12, 36, 15, 45]`

*NB. `b%2` is considered True if `b` is odd, else `False`*

Comment: are you sure the second way is more efficient? I'm finding it's 3x slower with the given data

Comment: @Nin17 you're right, stupid mistake of mine

Answer (score 2):

Try this, One-time computing odd elements from `list_2`.

```
odd_l2 = [l for l in list_2 if l%2]
res = [k*r for k in list_1 for r in odd_l2]
print(*res, sep='\n')
```

---

```
3
9
6
18
9
27
12
36
15
45
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
for x in list_1: # Iterate through list_1
    for y in list_2: # Iterate through list_2
        if y % 2: # If y is odd, output
            print(x, '*', y, '=', x*y) # or print(x*y) if you want just the result
```

Output:

```
1 * 3 = 3
1 * 9 = 9
2 * 3 = 6
2 * 9 = 18
3 * 3 = 9
3 * 9 = 27
4 * 3 = 12
4 * 9 = 36
5 * 3 = 15
5 * 9 = 45
```

---

Or, even simpler:

```py
odds = [x for x in list_2 if x % 2]
print(*[a*b for a in list_1 for b in odds], sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
3
9
6
18
9
27
12
36
15
45
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt

```py
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_2 = [2,3,6,8,9]

for element in list_1:
    for num in list_2:
        if num%2 != 0:
            print(num*element)
```

The output is:

```py
3
9
6
18
9
27
12
36
15
45
```